# Python thinks I'm passing 4 arguments, but I'm clearly only passing 3

Tags: python, arguments

The error is:

```
TypeError:  kernel() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

The corresponding code is:

```
K[i][j] = self.kernel(self, B[i], C[j])
...
def kernel(self, P, Q)
```

The results of the following lines were:

```
print self:  object at 0x....
print len((self, B[i], C[j])): 3
print len((B[i])): 4
print len((C[j])): 4
```

Why does it say 4 arguments are given and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bound methods have `self` *added* automatically, implicitly. Don't pass it in explicitly:

```
K[i][j] = self.kernel(self, B[i], C[j])
```

remove `self` there:

```
K[i][j] = self.kernel(B[i], C[j])
```

otherwise `kernel()` is called with `kernel(self, self, B[i], C[j])`, or 4 arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Note that

`obj_name.kernel(B[i], C[j])`

will do the same job that

`class_name.kernel(obj_name, B[i], C[j])`, where `obj_name` is an instance of `class_name` class.

So you need to call it as:

`K[i][j] = self.kernel(B[i], C[j])`

**Example:**

```
class C:
    def f(self, a):
        print "HI: " + str(a)

var = C()
var.f(1)
C.f(var, 1)
```

**Output:**

```
HI: 1
HI: 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Because in Python, `self` is implicitly passed as an argument to any member function of a class. So what you're really doing is passing two `self`s.

Just remove the `self` and it will fix the problem.

```
K[i][j] = self.kernel(B[i], C[j])
```